# Как правильно ставить nodejs в ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, gulp

Ставлю `sudo apt-get install nodejs npm`, потом 'sudo nodejs -v', показывает версию, правда старую. Но если написать в консоли `node`

> ivan@pc:~$ sudo node
>   sudo: node: command not found
>    ivan@pc:~$

И у меня не запускается gulp, пишет точно такую же ошибку. Что за дела?

Comment: Попробуйте `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: @Oceinic а какую версию он мне поставит? Убогую самую последнею стабильную?

Comment: Эта команда обновит все пакеты на последнюю стабильную версию. Кстати, какого года у Вас дистрибутив?

Comment: @Oceinic последнюю стабильную я не хочу ставить, с ней одни проблемы. Дестрибутив последней, тот что был до 15. То есть 14,хх

Comment: @Oceinic я скачал нужный nodejs архив, распаковал. Вы не подскажете, как его в путях прописать?

Comment: Ничего там вручную прописывать не нужно. Обычный configure - make - make install

Comment: @Oceinic а можно немного подробней?

Comment: Если хотите, можете задать отдельный вопрос - как установить nodejs из исходников. Но лучше сделаёте то, что я посоветовал в первом комментарии

Comment: @Oceinic сделал - ivan@pc:~$ sudo node
[sudo] password for ivan: 
sudo: node: command not found
ivan@pc:~$

Comment: Даже не знаю, что ещё Вам посоветовать. Эта ошибка говорит только о том, что программа не установлена

Comment: Советую попробовать [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) - легкая установка и одновременная поддержка разных версии Node.js

Answer (score 1):

В стандартном архиве могут храниться устаревшие версии. Попробуйте вот это:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo bash -
```

А потом уже:

```
apt-get install nodejs
```